# Return jQuery html Objects at once

Tags: jquery

How to return all three divs without passing plain html, as array, and without losing the reference.

```
function MyClass()
{
   var div1 = $('<div>Div1</div>');
   var div2 = $('<div>Div2</div>');
   var div3 = $('<div>Div3</div>');

   div1.click(function(){alert("a click!");})

   this.GetThem = function()
   {
       //return all three
   }
}

var my_class = new Class();
$('selector').append(my_class.GetThem())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
function MyClass() {
   var div1 = $('<div>Div1</div>');
   var div2 = $('<div>Div2</div>');
   var div3 = $('<div>Div3</div>');

   div1.click(function(){alert("a click!");})

   this.GetThem = function() {
       return div1.add(div2).add(div3);
   }
}

var my_class = new MyClass();
$('selector').append(my_class.GetThem())
```

Comment: Thats nice. How to use it in a for loop?

Comment: In a for loop how exactly ?

Comment: if div1,div2,div3,... were in a array.

Comment: Append works with arrays and array-like objects, so just pass it back to append.

Comment: wow, didnt know this. Now i return an array with all jquery html objects in it! Warm Greets to Norway :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to create a new jQuery wrapper element by concatenating two references

```
this.GetThem = function()
{
   return div1.add(div2).add(div3)
}
```